# Blender Eevee crazy render artifacts (maybe?)

Tags: rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

So I'm doing some work on Jim, about to texture, and boom, these crazy artifacts on some randomly selected faces...

I've tested the .blend file on my laptop and it all seems fine, and I've tested new .blend files and they tend to do the same. The texture shows fine in Cycles and I haven't done anything to the material except plug in the texture, I have also tried reinstalling Blender completely with no luck...

I do have a fairly old IMac, mid 2011 21.5", which might be the thing causing it, but any insight would be amazing <3

Any ideas?

Edit: I also get some weird stuff in shading mode too (black model, weird light sphere

[image: Jim and his crazy artifacts]
[image: Shading mode problems])

Comment: What version of macOS are you using and which graphics card is in you iMac? It could be that it doesn't meet the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/).

Comment: 10.13.6 HS and a Radeon HD 4670, realising now that it's a mid 2010